# Sum values based on grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list collection and need to find ProductNames that have same value and sum the EMV in the list.

```
var result = new List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>();

foreach (var ag in allocationsGrouped)
{
    var allocationsGroup = ag.Select(a => a).OrderByDescending(o=> o.UsdEmv ) ;

    CreateHierarchy(ag.Key, allocationsGroup, result);
}

result.GroupBy(x => x.ProductName);
```

```
private AllocationsViewModel GetAllocationsViewModel(int id, DateTime date)
{
    var ms = GetStrategy(id);

    DateTime d = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    if (ms.FIRM_ID != null)
    {
        var firm = GetService<FIRM>().Get(ms.FIRM_ID.Value);
        var currentEntity = new EntityAllocationsViewModel(new EntityViewModel { EntityId = firm.ID, EntityName = firm.NAME, EntityType = EntityType.Firm });
        //var allocationsGrouped = Mapper.Map<List<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>, List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>(GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d).ToList())

        //Mapper.Map<ILookup<string,FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>,ILookup<string,FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>((ILookup<string, FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>)

        var allocationsGrouped = GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d);
        var result = new List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>();

        foreach (var ag in allocationsGrouped)
        {
            var allocationsGroup = ag.Select(a => a).OrderByDescending(o => o.UsdEmv);

            CreateHierarchy(ag.Key, allocationsGroup, result);
        }

        result.GroupBy(x => x.ProductName);

        var missingProducts = Mapper.Map<List<MISSING_PRODUCT>, List<MissingProductsViewModel>>(GetMissingProducts()).GroupBy(a => a.ProductType);
        var chartData = Mapper.Map<List<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>, List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>(GetAllocationsCalculateOther(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d));

        var vm = new AllocationsViewModel
        {
            CurrentEntity = currentEntity,
            ManagerAllocations = result,
            MissingProducts = missingProducts,
            ChartData = chartData
        };

        return vm;
    }

    return null;
}


private static void CreateHierarchy(string manStratName, IEnumerable<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION> allocationsGrouped, List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel> result)
{
    var item = new FirmWideAllocationsViewModel();
    item.Hierarchy = new List<string>();

    item.Hierarchy.Add(manStratName);
    result.Add(item);
    foreach (var ac in allocationsGrouped)
    {
        var item2 = new FirmWideAllocationsViewModel();
        item2.Hierarchy = new List<string>();
        item2.Hierarchy.Add(manStratName);
        item2.Hierarchy.Add(ac.PRODUCT_NAME + "#" + ac.MANAGER_FUND_ID + ac.PRODUCT_ID + ac.EMV);
        item2.FirmID = ac.FIRM_ID;
        item2.FirmName = ac.FIRM_NAME;
        item2.ManagerStrategyID = ac.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID;
        item2.ManagerStrategyName = ac.MANAGER_STRATEGY_NAME;
        item2.ManagerAccountClassID = ac.MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_ID;
        item2.ManagerAccountingClassName = ac.MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_NAME;
        item2.ManagerFundID = ac.MANAGER_FUND_ID;
        item2.ManagerFundName = ac.MANAGER_FUND_NAME;
        item2.Nav = ac.NAV;
        item2.EvalDate = ac.EVAL_DATE.HasValue ? ac.EVAL_DATE.Value.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy") : string.Empty;
        item2.ProductID = ac.PRODUCT_ID;
        item2.ProductName = ac.PRODUCT_NAME;
        item2.UsdEmv = Math.Round((decimal)ac.UsdEmv);
        item2.GroupPercent = ac.GroupPercent;
        item2.WeightWithEq = ac.WEIGHT_WITH_EQ;
        result.Add(item2);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class FirmWideAllocationsViewModel
{
    public List<string> Hierarchy
    { get; set; }

    private decimal? _groupPercent;
    public int FirmID { get; set; }
    public string FirmName { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerStrategyID { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerFundID { get; set; }
    public int ManagerAccountClassID{ get; set; }
    public int? ManagerFundOrClassID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerFundName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerAccountingClassName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerStrategyName { get; set; }
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? Nav { get; set; }

    public string EvalDate { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultStrategyID { get; set; }
    public string DEFAULT_STRATEGY_NAME { get; set; }
    public decimal Usd_Emv { get; set; }

    //needed for kendo aggregates
    public decimal UsdEmv { get; set; }

    public decimal Emv { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? WeightWithEq { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal? Percent { get; set; } // manual calc

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal? GroupPercent
    {
        get { return _groupPercent; }
        set { _groupPercent = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. Can you pair this down to a [mcve]? For example, we don't care about your entire model - just the two properties you're concerned with.

Comment: I am not just summing up based on a product name . I need to sum up only if two or more  product names are same

Comment: Yes, you have to group by the product name, then for each group, sum the `Emv` property. It seems you already know how to use `GroupBy` in linq. The second link here tells you how to sum by a property.

Comment: I have tried to add as much minimal code as possible . Had I reduced the code , you would have asked for more . I have clearly stated the area of the code that needs focus in my post. The rest can be ignored if wanted as some might want to refer for extra information

Comment: Do I need to sum after doing group by. When I do that I don’t get the field name that I want to sum. I am getting something like sum(x=> x.key)

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a smaller example of something you're trying to do.

Model:

```
public class Product
{
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public decimal Emv { get; set; }
}
```

What you want in the end is to find the sum of the `Emv` *per each `ProductName`*.

```
public Dictionary<string, decimal> SumProductEmv(IEnumerable<Product> allProducts)
{
    return allProducts
        .GroupBy(product => product.ProductName)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            ProductName = group.Key, // this is the value you grouped on - the ProductName
            EmvSum = group.Sum(item => item.Emv)
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.ProductName, x => x.EmvSum);
}
```

The trick here is the when you are doing the `Sum` operation, it's against the `group`.

In this example I'm packaging the results into a dictionary for convenience. The key is the name of a product, and the value is the sum of all Emv values for products with that name.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some direction. I am getting error System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key'. is it because the first element of mine is null. How do ignore the but yet have it in my original list.  I need to pass list collection and not dictionary.